# Cannot connect to Azure Mobile Services Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to `Microsoft Azure` and am struggling to connect to an existing `Azure Mobile Service`. I'd like to add a service reference to this Mobile site in a `Console Application` in `Visual Studio 2015`.

When I right-click `References` -> `Add Connected Service` -> `Azure Mobile Services`, the **Configure Button is disabled** (see image):

[image]

- I've installed the `Azure SDK`
- I've added `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` via `NuGet`
- Tried right-click on project `Add` -> `Azure API App Client`, but the drop down of available services is empty. When I publish the Mobile Service from Visual Studio, it shows up in the drop down for *existing mobile services*
- I **successfully** connect to service using `Fiddler` and was able to query data.

Am I missing SDK or something?

Comment: have you got the answer

Comment: Yes, as @mattchenderson said in the answer, you can still connect with code manually. In your azure portal it provides you with a code snippet for the creating a `MobileServiceClient` instance. Paste that snippet into your code and you're golden.

Comment: MobileServiceClient LartMobileServiceClient= new MobileServiceClient(appurl, appkey) but showing waiting for activation..how can we activate azure service

Comment: @DeviPrasad, I recommend you create a new SO question for this. That way the community can help answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tooling gesture is not supported for this client type (console app). From this dialog, Mobile Services can be added to Windows and Cordova targets. The [More Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn872473.aspx) link from your screenshot shows the full details.

You can still connect to Mobile Services via the [SDK you obtained via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/1.3.2). You just have to install this manually, rather than using the tooling. In order to get started, create a `MobileServiceClient` object and pass it the URL of your app and the App Key (available in the management portal).

Comment: I added mobile service using SDK when i call table from mobile service it showing "waiting for activation" how activate mobile service in windows 10 apps